# How can I transfer my local database to another computer which does not have SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm writing a program with using C#. And I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to create local databases to keep my data. I would like to run this program on other computers. I do not want to install SQL Server Management Studio on every computer. Can I move my local database to other computers without installing SQL Server Management Studio?

In example I don't mind installing localDB. Actually I think that I can do it only using localDB but I could not find proper info. My program can reach the database with connections.

In other words, how can I move my database to another computer which ONLY has localDB?

Thanks...

Comment: What does "move" mean? SQL Server Management Studio is for *managing* databases, it is not a SQL Server engine. LocalDB means that you are working directly with `*.mdf` files, and yes, it's perfectly possible.

Comment: Have you considered SQLite? No install needed, it is just a dll and you program against it with Entity Framework or ADO.Net

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb):

> LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers. It is available on SQL Server 2016 Express with Advanced Services.
>   LocalDB installation copies a minimal set of files necessary to start the SQL Server Database Engine. Once LocalDB is installed, you can initiate a connection using a special connection string. When connecting, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically created and started, enabling the application to use the database without complex configuration tasks. Developer Tools can provide developers with a SQL Server Database Engine that lets them write and test Transact-SQL code without having to manage a full server instance of SQL Server.

You can work with LocalDb without having to install Management studio.

Comment: But how can create new database without man. studio? I learned that I could back-up the database and copy file to another PC  and restore it on another PC. But how can do it without sql server man. studio.

Comment: Read the section "Starting LocalDB and Connecting to LocalDB"